# how can I Count Number of Pages inside PDF Document of url and show it in html by using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to write code to show number of pages inside a pdf of any website pdf link (like google drive) or any local pc link. I have the code below, If I use a file type input in html and chose the pdf file from my pc then it's work, but when I try use it as type text then of course it doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Count Number of Pages inside PDF Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Count Pages inside PDF Document</h1>
            <div class="form-group container">
                <input type="text" accept=".pdf" required id="pdfFile" class="form-control"/>
                <button onclick="getNumberOfPages()">Get Number of Pages</button>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <h1 class="text-primary container" id="result"></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let inputElement = document.getElementById('pdfFile')
        function getNumberOfPages() {
            var file = inputElement.files[0];
    
            //Step 2: Read the file using file reader
            var fileReader = new FileReader();  
 
            fileReader.onload = function() {
 
                //Step 4:turn array buffer into typed array
                var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);
 
                //Step 5:pdfjs should be able to read this
                const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
                loadingTask.promise.then(pdf => {
 
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "The number of Pages inside pdf document is " + pdf.numPages
                    // The document is loaded here...
                });
                  [![enter image description here][1]][1] 
            };
            //Step 3:Read the file as ArrayBuffer
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I expect the output like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2UQH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of CORS you can't get a pdf file from Google Drive with pure javascript without npm and stuff. However, if you're getting the pdf from the domain that the page is hosted on then you can do this:

```js
async function getNumberOfPages() {
  const inputFileUrl = document.getElementById("pdfFile").value;  // gets the link from input
  // fetch file from server
  var f = await fetch(inputFileUrl);
  var response = await f.blob();

  // create a file reader
  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function() {
    var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);

    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
    loadingTask.promise.then(pdf => {

      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "The number of Pages inside pdf document is " + pdf.numPages
    });
  };
  // read file
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(response);
}

// add event listener to the button to execute the function
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  getNumberOfPages();
});
```

```html
<title>Count Number of Pages inside PDF Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<h1 class="text-center">Count Pages inside PDF Document</h1>
<div class="form-group container">
  <input type="text" accept=".pdf" required id="pdfFile" class="form-control" placeholder="example: https://localhost/sample.pdf" />
  <button id="btn">Get Number of Pages</button>
</div>
<br><br>
<h1 class="text-primary container" id="result"></h1>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```